# How to get unique values from a column that contains comma seperated data in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a table like this

```
| Id  | Name    |  skills                     |
|---- |---------|-----------------------------|
| 1   | John    | python, java, c++           |
| 2   | Mike    | c++, javascript             |
| 3   | Smith   | java, ruby, vuejs, python   |
```

I need to find all the unique values for the column skills.

Comment: Why did you come up with such table. Normally one creates two tables here: one for the `Person`, and one with an FK/M2M to `Person` for example `Skill`. Right now the data is no longer "structured".

Comment: I already have this kind of data and I cannot modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
skills_list = []
for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
    skills_list += obj.skills.split(", ")
unique_skills = list(set(skills_list))
```

If you are using PostgreSQL as your database, consider storing `skills` in an [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield). This will allow you to deal with it as a python list, and you wouldn't need to use `split.(", ")` in the above example.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question, how to find how many users having a skill `python`?

Comment: @AshwaniShakya - Try `MyModel.objects.filter(skills__contains='python').count()`